# Performance issue view with DENSE_RANK() in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have a requirement to get the records from the below tables with mentioned matching condition & limit the count of UNIQUE COL3 to 20K.

We have achieved this by  using `DENSE_RANK()` logic but we observed extremely slowness in performance when we have implemented in live system.

For processing 20K UNIQUE COL3 & 60K total records, it is taking 14-15 hours to complete (The process is running over a daily JOB & select FROM view & performing DML operation to few tables based on View records).

```
SELECT COUNT (distinct COL3) CNT1,COUNT(1) CNT2 FROM VW_ENTP;
--20,000                                                  60,000
```

**Without** the `DENSE_RAN()` logic it is finishing very fast but with `DENSE_RAN()` it extremely slow.

Request your help to share any recommendation to IMPROVE QUERY PERFORMANCE or any alternative approach. Thanks in advance !

#### Sample View Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_ENTP(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10) AS
SELECT
COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10
 FROM
(
SELECT
           NP.NFCD COL1,
           D.CLO2 COL2,
           NP.COL3 COL3,
           E.COL4 COL4,
           EDT.COL5,
           EDT.COL6,
           NP. COL7,
           NP. COL8,
           EDT.COL9 COL9,
           NP.COL10,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NP.COL3) RANK
  FROM ENP NP,EDTS EDT,EM E,EDT D,BDT BD
WHERE EDT.COL2=D.COL2
  AND E.COL3=NP.COL3
  AND E.COL7=NP.COL7
  AND E.COL8=NP.COL8
  AND E.APP=NP.APP
  AND NP.STATUS='P'
  AND NP.NFCD=D.COL1
  AND E.SUSP !='YES'
  AND NP.APP='EDOC'
  AND TRUNC(NP.RC_DATE)<=TRUNC(BD.LAST_RUN_DATE)
)
  WHERE RANK<=20000;
```

Note : The above used columns are indexed.

Comment: Hello Experts-Any update on this? Any thought would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by row_number() function only:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_ENTP(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10) AS
SELECT
COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10
 FROM
(select a.*, row_number() over (order by col3) rn from (
SELECT
           NP.NFCD COL1,
           D.CLO2 COL2,
           NP.COL3 COL3,
           E.COL4 COL4,
           EDT.COL5,
           EDT.COL6,
           NP. COL7,
           NP. COL8,
           EDT.COL9 COL9,
           NP.COL10,
           row_number() OVER (partition by np.col3 ORDER BY NP.COL3) RANK
  FROM ENP NP,EDTS EDT,EM E,EDT D,BDT BD
WHERE EDT.COL2=D.COL2
  AND E.COL3=NP.COL3
  AND E.COL7=NP.COL7
  AND E.COL8=NP.COL8
  AND E.APP=NP.APP
  AND NP.STATUS='P'
  AND NP.NFCD=D.COL1
  AND E.SUSP !='YES'
  AND NP.APP='EDOC'
  AND TRUNC(NP.RC_DATE)<=TRUNC(BD.LAST_RUN_DATE)
) a where rank > 1 and rank <= 20000)
```

;

Current Query results :

COL3   RANK

1      1

2      1

3      1

3      2

3      3

3      4

4      1

5      1

Requirement :

COL3   RANK

1      1

2      2

3      3

3      3

3      3

3      3

4      4

5      5

Comment: Hi Vinish-For your information COL3 is having the duplicate record ,the rank logic has been used to limit 20k duplicate COL3 for each time the view called.

Comment: Have you tried the above query? You try it should work... no need to use dense rank .. your purpose will solve with this..

Comment: I don't think substituting a different analytic function would address the performance issue. Do you have a benchmark which demonstrates a substantial performance improvement for `row_number()` over `dense_rank()`?

Comment: oh.. put a (alias) as following: ) a where rank = 1) 
  WHERE Rn <= 20000 .. i have changed the query in the answer..

Comment: Executed the query but i am only seeing the unique record count now(refer the below output)
the requirement is to fetch all the duplicate COL3 but count for each COL3 should be <=20k


SELECT COUNT (distinct COL3) CNT1,COUNT(1) CNT2 FROM VW_ENTP;
--20,000                           20,000

Comment: After adding the condition to  where rank >= 1 and rank <= 20000 getting the right result set. Not sure how will it help in performance standpoint which is very important.
will update once will execute this view through job.

Comment: Hi -I have tested the SQL & could see the ranking is not working properly due to that the filter condition (rank <= 20000)
also not working (it is not restricting 20K records),please find the sample data in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if any join condition is missed it leads to poor performance. Also you're joining few other tables and any of the tables can be causing the performance issue. Suggestion for them can be given only after having look at those tables.

To confirm if dense rank is causing the issue, you can remove it and execute the select statement. If it takes less time, then you can conclude dense rank is causing the issue. But I highly suspect it'll happen.

Comment: yes,we have executed the SQL with out the dense rank it is working as expected.

Comment: Then remove the rank from the select statement. Put the select statement in WITH clause. Then apply the rank function on the result of WITH class. It must work.

Comment: Without rank function performance is fine. With rank function the performance is bad - That's impossible. I think you're either lying or making mistake in the code. What is the resulting record count without rank function and your oracle version?

Comment: Oracle version-> Oracle 12c Enterprise edition
Record processing->
SELECT COUNT (distinct COL3) CNT1,COUNT(1) CNT2 FROM VW_ENTP;
--19,000                                                  30,000